# libmad error in yocto krogoth 2.1.2

Tags: yocto, build-system

I am compiling libmad in yocto-2.1.2 its giving below error.

```
Nothing PROVIDES 'libmad'libmad was skipped: because it has a restricted license not whitelisted in LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST
```

How to resove this error. THanks in advance.

I'm compiling `libmad` for [python-pygame](https://github.com/yoctopidge/meta-hurdy/blob/master/recipes-multimedia/pygame/python-pygame_1.9.1.bb) recipe in yocto(toaster).

Comment: I suppose you have a problem with the licensing...

Answer (score 4):

In the `libmad` recipe, there's a line

```
LICENSE_FLAGS = "commercial"
```

which means that you might require a commercial license (depending on jurisdiction etc. This can often be the case for eg media encoders / decoders).

If / when you have solved that issue (either by obtaining a commercial license, or deemed that you don't need one), you should add:

```
LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST += "commercial_libmad"
```

in your `local.conf` or in your distro config.

Comment: Thanks@anders, I'm using toaster 2.1.2 and I have added the above line still its showing same error. how can i recompile that.

Comment: Where did you add that line? Could you run `bitbake libmad -e |grep WHITELIST` and paste the output here.

Comment: Dear Anders, I am using web interface(toaster) not bibake. below is my local.conf file # track the version of this file when it was generated. This can safely be ignored if
..............
CONF_VERSION = "1"
INHERIT+="toaster buildhistory"
LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST += "commercial_libmad"
~

Comment: Well, I just confirmed that what's above works perfectly well when manually running `bitbake`. Thus, I'd say that you have to look closer, and verify that `LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST` is actually seen and used by your toaster builds. I'd also recommend you to make a testbuild running `bitbake` by hand...

Comment: I am here to confirm that the answer of Anders is correct.  Toaster is limited.  Please use bitbake instead.